# Is it possible to match half of a string using regex or use half of a matched group?

Tags: javascript, regex, v8

I have a string of the following form "some_text_AAAABB_some_other_text". There is an arbitrary even number of 'A's in the string and "BB" is a fixed string that follows the 'A's. Assuming that there is *2n* 'A's I would like to use a regex to replace the 'A's with a string of 'A's of length *n*.

For the following string

```
"some_text_AAAABB_some_other_text"
```

the result would be

```
"some_text_AABB_some_other_text"
```

Is it even possible to achieve this with regex?

I'm using V8 javascript to perform the transformation.

Comment: What is the tool/proramming language you are using, Marcinie? Also, what is the expected output for `"some_text_AAAAABB_some_other_text"`?

Comment: To match an *even* number of `A`s, you could come up with [`(?:A{2})+`](https://regex101.com/r/oY8eF9/1). As @WiktorStribiżew pointed out however, what shall be done with *odd* occurences?

Comment: match it with `(A+)\1` and replace the match by `\1`.

Comment: Yes, [`replace(/(A+)\1BB/g, '$1BB')`](https://regex101.com/r/tE9eO3/3) should work. Still not clear what we should do in case of odd amount of characters.

Comment: It does work, thx! We don't care about odd number of 'A's. It is provided that there is an even number of 'A's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two scenarios: 1) number of `A`s is even, 2) number of `A`s is odd.

If you do not care if there is an even or odd number of `A`s, just use

```
replace(/(A+)\1BB/g, "$1BB")
```

where `(A+)` matches and captures into Group 1 one or more `A`s *as many as possible* and `\1` matches the same substring (the same number as is captured into Group 1). Since `BB` is a fixed string, we just put it into the pattern as a literal.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tE9eO3/3)

If you do not want to modify a string with odd number of `A`s, you need

```
replace(/(^|[^A-Z])(A+)\2BB/g, "$1$2BB")
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tE9eO3/4)

Here, the first capture group captures the start of string `^` or any character other than `[A-Z]`, the *second* capture group captures 1 or more `A`s, and the backreference now has the **ID = 2** - hence, `\2` is used.

Comment: Still, the odd number of `A`s scenario might be useful for future readers, so I added that bit.